# Is there a way to enable qt quick/qml doc/help in qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator, qt-quick

Qt doc was very helpful, I could always look up what methods does the certain object have, what args do they take and what do they do and return. But trying to build my app with qml is really frustrating. Not only I have to manually modify ui.qml file for qt items to be accessible, but I can only get available methods look-up without any documentation. This really discourages me as I have to spend a lot of time browsing through online documentation trying to guess how to do simple thing. (The fact the errors/warning only appear after I compile doesn't help)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here -- as long as the documentation is installed, all you have to do is move your text cursor to the name of a component, for example "Rectangle," and hit F1 to open the associated help page.

Comment: when my next question would be how to instal qml/qtquick documentation? Qt++ one was already included.

Answer (score 0):

Qt creator has inbuilt documentation for both Qt classes and qml. All you need is to press F1 while cursor is on the respective element. Here is the detailed description of using it :

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-help.html

Comment: Thanks but that's half of my problem (I found out you could do this in meantime). It still lacks "inline" documentations for methods. So if I want to know what type are args or what does some method do I need to find out declaration of that qml object , press f1 on it and find method description there.